# points system based on how many points you have

Tags: php

I am working to create a point system, points system should be such that 0-250 says nice points clear or look like, and from 251 up to 500 says it just points 310 - woow example, what I want it to do it is the need to find out where is the point that is if I have 1000 points so it will show the area of ​​text that only 1,000 to 5,000

That is, 0-249 supposed to mean something specific and then after it shall find something new.

I've tried to do like this:

```
<?php
        if($point >= 0)
        {
            echo "Point: " . $point;
        }
        elseif($point >= 10)
        {
            echo "Point: " . $point . " WoooW!";
        }
        elseif($point >= 500)
        {
            echo "Point: " . $point . " Beautiful clear!";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the order of the IFs.

```
<?php
if($point >= 500)
{
    echo "Point: " . $point . " Beautiful clear!";
}
elseif($point >= 250)
{
    echo "Point: " . $point . " WoooW!";
}
elseif($point >= 0)
{
    echo "Point: " . $point;
}
?>
```

Comment: Indeed : `if`s are treated in the code order, and the success of one block will cancel any possible execution of the others.

Comment: Yes, and the last one could be a simple else as well.

Comment: Thanks guys for help, and nice for fast support!

Answer (score 1):

You can either reverse the order of the `if` statements, as shown in user179572's answer, or invert the conditions:

```
if ($point < 10) {
    stuff to do for under 10 points
} else if($point < 100) {
    stuff to do for under 100 points
} else {
    stuff to do for 100 or more points
}
```